# Format date sql

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

Good day , i'm kind of struggling at the moment and this might be really easy for you , but i'm really new in sql .

I'm trying to change the format of a date from 2021-10-05 to Tue-05-Oct . in a htm file using SQL

I'm struggling cause i do not really understand how to use the convert or formatdate with an object (Select date.birthday as object) .

I'm a bit lost :(

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date using the MySQL [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

For example:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`myDate`, '%a-%d-%b') as textDate from `myTable`
```

which will return a date in the form `Tue-05-Oct`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this directly in crystal reports by creating a formula field as follows.

```
totext({ReplaceWithDataFieldToFormat},"ddd-dd-MMM")
```